# Download file (using NSURLDownload) after Login (using POST Request)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I am trying to download a file using NDURL Download. For that, I have to log in to a site.
I do this using a `NSMutableURLRequest` that I send using `sendSynchronousRequest` of `NSURLConnection`
The data that I receive from that message call is indeed the html page confirming my successful login.
To download the file I use the following code:

```
 NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.domain.com/getfile.php?file=1"]
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                        timeoutInterval:60.0];
// Create the connection with the request and start loading the data.
NSURLDownload  *theDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
                                                            delegate:self];
if (theDownload) {
    // Set the destination file.
    NSLog(@"Starting Download...");
    NSLog(@"%@", [theDownload description]);

    [theDownload setDestination:destinationFilename allowOverwrite:YES];
    pathToZipFile = destinationFilename;

} else {
    NSLog(@"Download failed...");
    return nil;
}
```

But the data I receive is the HTML page telling me I have to be logged in to download the file.
Any idea on this one?
Does the NSURLDownload have an different session than the NSURLConnection?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so you have logged in and then you trying to download a file. But how the server knows you are the same user that has logged in before?

There are different ways how it can know it. Some cookie, some request parameter, some HTTP header. But you have to add something to the request, that says "I am the user that has logged in a minute ago".

Answer (score 0):

I feel you have to implement delegates for NSURLDownload, like this :

```
- (void)downloadDidBegin:(NSURLDownload *)download{

}



- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
      _totalLength = response.expectedContentLength;
}



- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download willResumeWithResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response fromByte:(long long)startingByte{

}



- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didReceiveDataOfLength:(NSUInteger)length{
    _recievedLength = _recievedLength + length;
}



- (void)downloadDidFinish:(NSURLDownload *)download{
    //Completed//
}



- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //Error
}
```